# generate a random number that run x amount of times. Depending on what the user inputs in javascripit

Tags: javascript

I want to create a javascript program that lets you generate a random number that run x amount of times. Depending on what the user inputs. but I have tried too many times and its still not working.

Here is my code :

```js
function randomString() {

  var totalIterations = parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value);
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  output.innerHTML = '';

  var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var string_length = 8;
  var randomstring = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    randomstring = randomstring + chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
    for (var randomstring = 0; randomstring <= totalIterations; i++) {
      var item = document.createElement('div');
      item.innerHTML = randomstring;
      output.appendChild(item);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="randform">
<input type="button" id="input" value="Create Random String" 
onClick="randomString();">&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="randomfield" value="">
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: You want to have only 1 `for-loop`. The last one. Also take `item.innerHTML = randomstring;
        output.appendChild(item);` out of the `loop`.

Comment: You want to have `total iterations` based on the entry the user gives. But you hard-code it to 8. Also you have the wrong `input` for `totalIterations`.

Comment: the 8 is for the number of random lengths.

Comment: So you want for every `character` in `input` a `string` of `length` 8?

Comment: yes, run the code and see

Comment: The `code` is — not — running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code :

- line 3 : you're reading user input from the `input` element, which is a button
- line 13 : you're declaring randomstring again, and this time making it a number. There is no block scope in JavaScript, so by that, you're re-declaring an existing local variable.
- line 13 : you're incrementing `i` in your second for loop. I don't know what that it's about.
- also, in your HTML code, your button input tag is not closed

I fixed all the above issues in the snippet below. Is that what you were trying to achieve?

```js
function randomString() {

  var totalIterations = parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value);
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  output.innerHTML = '';

  var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var stringLength = 8;
  
  for (var iterations = 0; iterations < totalIterations; iterations++) {
    var item = document.createElement('div');
    // generating the randomString by calling another function : 
    item.innerHTML = generateRandomString(stringLength, chars);
    output.appendChild(item);
  }
}

function generateRandomString(length, chars) {
    var randomstring = '';
    // generating the random string
    for (var i = 0; i <  length ; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring = randomstring + chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
    }
    
    return randomstring;
}
```

```html
<form name="randform">
<input type="button"  value="Create Random String" 
onClick="randomString();">&nbsp;</input>
<input type="text" id="input" name="randomfield" value="">
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Now that I see where you want to go, I would strongly advise you to use another function to generate the randomstring. It would make your code more readable.

Comment: yes it is, but its printing out the same random strings, i want it to print out different strings at once

Comment: so is it possible to store it in an array and upload it to a database?

Comment: @TopeKenny it is possible. But this code is executed in a browser (client side). You will need a back-end application to store your generated strings in a database.

Comment: alright.please can you make it more clear to me, i rearly understand. that means i have to change all my code to php or what?

Comment: You can code in JavaScript on server-side with NodeJS. There are several guides on how to use NodeJS and a database, for instance MySQL : https://www.sitepoint.com/using-node-mysql-javascript-client/

Answer (score 0):

You have to change some code 
add id to you input like id="randNum"
function randomString() {

```
//and use id instead of input because it is selecting first input element;
var totalIterations = parseInt(document.getElementById('#randNum').value);
// Add # before output;
var output = document.getElementById('#output');
output.innerHTML = '';

var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var string_length = 8;
var randomstring = '';
for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    randomstring= randomstring + chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    for(var randomstring=0; randomstring <= totalIterations; i ++) {
    var item = document.createElement('div');
    item.innerHTML = randomstring;
    output.appendChild(item);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following can help:

```js
    const pickRandom = (min,max)=>
      Math.floor(Math.random()*max)+min;

    const pickFrom = array =>
      array[pickRandom(0,array.length-1)];

    const pick = (array,amount,doubles) => {
      const recur = (numbers,array) => {
        if(numbers.length>=amount){
          return [numbers,array];
        }
        const picked = pickFrom(array);
        return recur(
          numbers.concat(picked),
          array.filter(item=>item!==picked || doubles)
        );
      }
      return recur([],array);
    }
    

    console.log(pick(
      "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split(""),
      10,//how many characters
      true//if double values are allowed
    )[0].join())
```